# Regex to not accept invalid characters except JSON braces and colon

Tags: java, json, regex

I need to set up a validation rule for request params using RegEx. The rule should not allow invalid characters except json's ("{}", "[]", ":").

For example:

```
    "Piece" -> correct
    
    "Piece$%" -> incorrect
    
    {"labelName": "myName"} -> correct
```

However, my RegEx does not pass json format inputs.

```
    [a-zA-Z0-9\s{}:\[]]+
```

Comment: is that the exact regex ? because that doesn't match any of your lines at all, the first closing square bracket needs to be escaped, for now it ends the list of values, and it ends by `]+` so multiple bracket

Comment: @user16320675 Can u please show how it should look ?) I'm just new at Regular Expressions

Comment: Do you want a regex that matches valid json? If so, do you want the only match sensible key names - ie ones that are letters only and camel case?

Comment: @Bohemian Validate for valid json would be just perfect) and simple strings are also acceptable

Comment: `"[a-zA-Z0-9\"\\s\\{\\}:\\[\\]]+"`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The rule should not allow invalid characters except json's ("{}", "[]", ":")." I can't understand the problem. What is an invalid character? What is the rule that tells you so? Why are those JSON characters invalid, and why should we accept them anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve your check by negating the logic. Instead of looking for the characters allowed, you could look for any character which is not allowed. If your regex finds any match then the json is not consistent.

This regex looks for anything that is not a word character (letter or number), a white space or a json's symbol ([, ], {, }, :, " or a comma)

```
[^\w\s\{\}\[\]\:\",]
```

Here there is a link to test the regex.

https://regex101.com/r/7pn2FD/2